# Why doesn’t nucleus $^{160}$Tb fission from its ground state?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, radiation, half-life

Why doesn’t nucleus $^{160}$Tb( β decay with a half-life 72 days) fission from its ground state? (assuming a mass-symmetric split in two nuclei, $^{80}$As and $^{80}$Ge)

And how could $^{160}$Tb be theoretically made to fission but cannot working in reactor practically?

Comment: Is there a reason that you're asking about terbium in particular? FWIW, here's a related paper: https://journals.aps.org/prc/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevC.48.87

Comment: Well, the combination of 80As and 80Ge is indeed lower in energy than 160Tb. A perusal of ENDF finds no measured cross section for a neutron-induced fission reaction.